# Can't load my script into the footer of my WordPress theme

Tags: javascript, wordpress, function

It's certainly a noob question and I assume it, but i can't even load my couple of scripts + jQuery in my footer of my WP theme.

below is the code from `functions.php` :

```
<?php
function add_theme_scripts() {

  wp_register_style('style', plugins_url('style.css', __FILE__));

  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.12.3', true);
  wp_enqueue_script( 'popper', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/popper.min.js', array('jquery'),'', true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'plugin', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/plugin.js', array('jquery'),'', true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array('jquery'),'', true );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_scripts' );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have a call to wp_footer() in footer.php in your theme before the closing  tag
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_footer/

Comment: What do you mean exactly? this : `<?php get_footer(); ?>` ?

Comment: Yep, that should be before the closing body tag